# Java based version of LC-3 VM not working as expected

Tags: java, virtual-machine, lc3

Long story short I was trying to implement the LC-3 VM in Java by following the instructions at https://justinmeiners.github.io/lc3-vm/. I managed to get it running fine but it's not working as expected.

Your help in troubleshooting is appreciated and sorry in advance if this sounds like I am asking someone else to write my code (it sure sounds like that I know!).

The code is on github: https://github.com/fizaan/lc3vm-java.git

Issue:
So as soon as the program starts the user is prompted with a y/n question. But upon entering "y" the program replies "y is not a valid input" when it should actually move on to the next step of the program. Even entering "n" at the prompt gets similar results.

I have added instructions in the readme in the git link to compile and run the code.

Comment: It would be much better if you could insert to the question, a more detailed info on what "it's not working as expected" means, the case where you found it doesn't work as expected, desired behaviour and the part of your code which you think may cause the problem. That could help other readers to quicker identify and solve your problem.  (Keep the links but add some details)

Comment: My bad! So as soon as the program starts the user is prompted with a y/n question. But upon entering "y" the program replies "y is not a valid input" when it should actually move on to the next step of the program. Even entering "n" at the prompt gets similar results.

Comment: Okk, what about the rest of details? And I quickly went through your code and couldnt find the "is not a valid input", so where it comes from? The raw object, or something precompiled in your code? Please EDIT the question and add as much details as possible. (having that info in question - not in comments - is the key for bigger possibility of getting an answer).

Comment: The java code is a VM which executes the image 2048.obj (machine code). That "not valid" results come from it (the machine code) :). You see this java code is meant to run any LC-3 image file, theoritically.